# Is it necessary to reset after preview of a datasource? When else should reset be used?

Tags: matlab

In this matlab [example](http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/what-is-a-datastore.html), the `reset` function is frequently used. It is meant to reset the datastore to unread state so that previously read entries can be read again.

However, it is unclear to me whether previewing the data (using `preview`) constitutes reading from the datastore, so I am unsure whether I need to use reset after `previewing`.

Are there any other functions (other than `read`) that will necessitate a `reset` as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not necessary to reset after previewing a datasource, according to  http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/read-and-analyze-data-in-keyvaluedatastore-for-mat-file.html:

> datastore returns a KeyValueDatastore. The datastore function automatically determines the appropriate type of datastore to create.
>
> Preview the data using the preview function. This function does not affect the state of the datastore.